# search the element in array using angular 4

Tags: arrays, angular

I have array list of items like the below

```
 let sourceList: SourceList[] = [
  {
    Value: "L7",
    Name: "L7",
    IsVisible: false
  },
  {
    Value: "LO",
    Name: "LO",
    IsVisible: false
  },
  {
    Value: "L3",
    Name: "L3",
    IsVisible: false
  },
  {
    Value: "LS",
    Name: "LS",
    IsVisible: false
  }
]
```

code tried so far

```
 if(this.sourceList.indexOf("L7",0) != -1 && this.selectedSources.indexOf("LO",0) != -1 ){

  }
```

but getting an error at "**L7**"

I am adding items from this  souceList array to another array say array2 one by one ..
is there any way to check whether the item from the  souceList array is in array2 or not ..

I need to do some process if item **"L7"** and **"LO"** is in array 2
but I am not able to figure out how can i search both the items at a time in array 2 ..
I am using angular 4 ..

Could any one please help on this, that would be very grateful to me

Comment: What's the code you have so far for doing the search? There's also the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
if (this.sourceList.some(x => x.Value === "L7") &&
    this.selectedSources.some(x => x.Value === "L0")) {
  ...
}
```